# What is the literal expression of NaN in Neo4j Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I express NaN as a literal in a Cypher query?

**Situation**

I have a NaN value in a database:

```
match (a) with max(a.CONCENTRATION) as m return m
```

will return

```
m
---
NaN
```

[Cypher reference in Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/) mentioned that this is possible as the result of special value being stored:

> The special value java.lang.Double.NaN is regarded as being larger than all other numbers.

**What I tried**

However, now that it's in there, I don't know how to match them in search, because you get the following error

input

```
match (a) where a.CONCENTRATION = NaN return a limit 10
```

error

```
Variable `NaN` not defined (line 1, column 35 (offset: 34))
```

**Other references**

[Cypher reference in Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/) doesn't mention NaN literal, unless I missed it.

I've googled 'Cypher NaN' but the closest thing I got is how to add inf/NaN, which wasn't directly addressed ([How to add infinity, NaN, or null values to a double[] property on a node in Cypher/Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980830/how-to-add-infinity-nan-or-null-values-to-a-double-property-on-a-node-in-cyp)).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194534/how-to-determine-property-value-type-within-a-node-in-neo4j maybe you checked that, it should help you a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[UPDATE 2]

Neo4j 5.0 introduced:

- the [float literals](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/5/syntax/expressions/#cypher-expressions-general) `Inf`, `Infinity`, and `NaN`.
- the [isNaN()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/5/functions/mathematical-numeric/#functions-isnan) function for determining whether the specified value is `NaN`.

[ORIGINAL]

There is no way to specify the literal, but this should work:

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE TOFLOAT(a.CONCENTRATION) <> a.CONCENTRATION
RETURN a
LIMIT 10;
```

`TOFLOAT()` will return NULL if the argument cannot be converted (as needed) to a number. But, even if the argument can be converted, the result would not equal the argument unless it was numeric to begin with.

[UPDATE 1]

@chaserino's nice new answer prompted me to do a little more experimentation.

Although there is still no literal for `NaN`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity`, I determined that Cypher can generate those values in neo4j version 3.4.0+ (I did not test earlier versions). You can then use those values for comparison purposes.

For example, this query shows how to generate those values:

```
RETURN 0.0/0.0, 1.0/0.0, -1.0/0.0
```

And here is the result:

```
╒═════════╤═════════╤══════════╕
│"0.0/0.0"│"1.0/0.0"│"-1.0/0.0"│
╞═════════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│NaN      │Infinity │-Infinity │
└─────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

*NOTE: For `Infinity`, you can actually use any positive numerator, and for `-Infinity`, you can use any negative numerator.*

Answer (score 2):

This works in Neo4j 3.5:

MATCH (a)
WHERE TOSTRING(a.CONCENTRATION) = 'NaN'
RETURN a
LIMIT 10;

Comment: This method works for ` toString(entity.value) = 'Infinity' ` too, which was what I needed.

Comment: Thanks!
Works in Neo4j +4.0 too.